# Auto logout if browser is closed

Tags: php

I have a requirement like, if user closes browser then upon the next access of the site user should be asked to login again: I have written the following code in **`.htaccess`** file which is working fine:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>    
    #Session timeout    
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 1200    
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200    
</IfModule>
```

I am excited to know am I doing the correct thing, or is there any other best way to do this?

Comment: Well, as far as i know, if you do your login with `$_SESSION`s, that's the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [session cookie parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before you start your session.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Zero means ["until the browser is closed"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

This solution would be my personal "best" way of doing it, because you can control it per PHP-script, instead of site-wide. Also, it is clear from the PHP code, instead of relying on server-dependent settings.